# Convert screenshot (Graphics) to Mat directly | OpenCvSharp

Tags: c#, opencv

Currently I am implementing image recognition using OpenCvSharp.
I am creating a program that takes screenshots and performs recognition using them.

However, I don't know how to convert the screenshot directly to Mat, so I save it as a file.

```
Bitmap my_bmp = new(my_rectangle.Width, my_rectangle.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
Graphics my_graphics = Graphics.FromImage(my_bmp);
my_graphics.CopyFromScreen(my_rectangle.X, my_rectangle.Y, 0, 0, my_rectangle.Size);
my_bmp.Save("screenshots/theimage.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

Mat mat = new("screenshots/theimage.png");
```

This performance is the worst. How can I convert a screenshot directly to Mat?

Comment: do you have a pointer to the data, like a flat C array?